# Overlapping nodes in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes, tikz-chains

I used to make a chain diagram in tikz, like described in the [manual](ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) p. 59 ff, but in contrast to the manual, my nodes are overlapping. I tried to use the "node distance" option but i doesn't seem to work. Below is the minimal working [example (writeLatex.com)](https://www.writelatex.com/234963clhcwn):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tb]
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            % copy to preamble to use it everywhere \tikzset{node/.style...}
            node/.style={
                % shape
                rectangle,
                rounded corners=1mm,
                minimum size=6mm,
                %border
                thick,
                draw,
            },
            dummy/.style={
                % shape
                rectangle,
                rounded corners=1mm,
                minimum size=6mm,
                %border
                thick,
            },
            node distance=10mm
            ]
            \node(wadl)[node]{WADL-Datei};
            \node(xsd1)[node,below left of=wadl]{XSD-Datei};
            \node(...)[dummy,below of=wadl]{\ldots};
            \node(xsd3)[node,below right of=wadl]{XSD-Datei};
            \node(test)[node,right of=wadl]{test};

            \path(wadl) edge[->] (test);
        \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{center}
    \caption{Codegeneratorsystem}
    \label{fig:codegeneratorsystem}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Related (and explains this behavior): [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386)

Comment: By the way, you talk of chains and use the [tag:tikz-chains] tag but actually do not use the `chains` library (which uses the superior `positioning` library automatically and can simplify the creation of chain diagrams in certain aspects). Also, a node name of `...` calls for trouble as TikZ uses the `.` to separate node name and node anchor in the implicit node coordinate syntax. You won’t be able to reference any of `...`’s anchors nor use it with the `positioning` library as a reference node.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To have the nodes properly positionated relative to other nodes, you have to include the `positioning` tikz library. and change the syntax of your relative positioning from `below of=node` to `below = of node`, i.e., the equal sign comes before the `of` keyword.

This way:

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{figure}[tb]
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            % copy to preamble to use it everywhere \tikzset{node/.style...}
            node/.style={
                % shape
                rectangle,
                rounded corners=1mm,
                minimum size=6mm,
                %border
                thick,
                draw,
            },
            dummy/.style={
                % shape
                rectangle,
                rounded corners=1mm,
                minimum size=6mm,
                %border
                thick,
            },
            node distance=10mm
            ]
            \node(wadl)[node]{WADL-Datei};
            \node(xsd1)[node,below left=of wadl]{XSD-Datei};
            \node(...)[dummy,below= of wadl]{\ldots};
            \node(xsd3)[node,below right=of wadl]{XSD-Datei};
            \node(test)[node,right=of wadl]{test};

            \path(wadl) edge[->] (test);
        \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{center}
    \caption{Codegeneratorsystem}
    \label{fig:codegeneratorsystem}
\end{figure}
```

Which produces this result:

[image: Result]

Comment: I'm always amazed how fast i get an answer here :)
The tikz manual seems to be a bit misleading, because `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` is mentioned only one time in chapter 16.

Comment: While I don’t know OP’s expectation of the diagram, one can left-align the `test` and the `XSD-Datei` node by using `node distance=10mm and 10mm`, this changes the behavior of the combines keys like `below right`.

Answer (score 6):

Just add

`\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`

to your preamble and change your usage of positioning to:

```
\node(wadl)[node]{WADL-Datei};
\node(xsd1)[node,below left = of wadl]{XSD-Datei};
\node(...)[dummy,below = of wadl]{\ldots};
\node(xsd3)[node,below right = of wadl]{XSD-Datei};
\node(test)[node,right = of wadl]{test};
```

Answer (score 1):

An other option

```
    \node(wadl)[node]{WADL-Datei};
    \node(xsd1)[node,below left=10pt and 10pt of wadl ]{XSD-Datei};
    \node(...)[dummy,below of=wadl]{\ldots};
    \node(xsd3)[node,below right=10pt and 10pt of wadl]{XSD-Datei};
    \node(test)[node,right=10pt of wadl]{test};
    \path(wadl) edge[->] (test);
```

[image]

Comment: I dont think that this is a real option, because (semi-)manual positioning of nodes is towards the intentions to use tikz/pgf for graphics creation.